# POSTFIX not sending email to 1and1 main only

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vps, postfix-mta

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 with POSTFIX on my 1and1 VPS, I am having problem to sending email to my own email.

When I sent emails to:

- outlook.com RECEIVED
- yahoo.com RECEIVED
- Gmail.com RECEIVED
- example.co.uk (1and1 mail) NOT RECEIVED

main.cf

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.co.uk
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_protocols = all
```

Comment: You're getting any Mail delivery errors or something else? How do you try to send the mail, web interface, cli etc.?

Comment: I have tried sending by php mail().

Comment: also I am not getting any mail delivery error, my mail.log is empty

Comment: Might be that you're not getting errors if you try to send it through php. You tried to send a mail through outlook or so to your domain? Have you tried that you can resolve your domain from within your host?

Comment: example.co.uk is hosted on 1and1 mail server so its MX record set to mx00.1and1.co.uk and we are receiving all email from all other server.

Comment: I have test to send email from cli command also but still mail not received. mail -s "this is test mmail" support@example.co.uk < message_body.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had checked my mailqueue by `mailq` command so I was getting errors : `(delivery temporarily suspended: host mx01.1and1.co.uk[xxx.xx.xxx.xx] refused to talk to me: 554-kundenserver.de (mxeue105) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 554-No SMTP service 554 invalid DNS PTR resource record, IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` so I just added a PTR(Reverse DNS) entry.

Now its working :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Please consider accepting your answer as the one, which solved your issue.